# How to set t-params.bind in a pair Map in Aurelia?

Tags: localization, aurelia

I have a pair Map like the following code in Aurelia:

```
public intervals = new Map<number, { key: string}>();

this.intervals.set(1, {key: "immediately"});
this.intervals.set(2, {key: "eight-hours"});
this.intervals.set(3, {key: "seven-days"});
```

By repeat.for I want to set a Context for localization purpose as you see in the following:

```
<select class="combobox" value.bind="errorIntervall">
          <option model.bind="null" t="network.empty">-</option>
          <option repeat.for="[number, key] of intervals" t="system.network.intervall"
                  t-params.bind="{ context: key }">
            ></option>
</select>
```

Here is my translation.json file too:

```
"network": {
  "intervall_immediately": "Immediately",
  "intervall_eight-hours": "every 8 h",
  "intervall_seven-days": "every 7 days"
},
```

I did not find any way to access intervals.key .
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, as you see in the following:

```
<select class="combobox" value.bind="errorIntervall">
          <option model.bind="null" t="system.network.empty">-</option>
          <option repeat.for="[number, interval] of intervals"
                  model.bind="interval"
                  t="system.network.interval"
                  t-params.bind="{ context: interval.key }">
            ></option>
</select>
```